# Edit Button Not Displaying on Modern Sites SharePoint 2019 on Premise

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

modern sites on my site collection do not have a working edit button. The issue is inconsistent, Previously it was working but from last couple of days Edit button is not showing.

1. I have full control over the entire collection, so permissions shouldn't be the issue.
2. I tried multiple browsers, windows clearing the browser cache, and have determined that it's universally affecting all users regardless of browser.
3. Tried to add "?ToolPaneView=2&Mode=Edit" to the url to check whether they could be edited still it's not working.
4. I can confirm that these sites were editable a couple of days ago, After, Did R&D on that
   i came across to know that i need to install latest Sharepoint updates.
   So i updated kb5002135 to kb5002180 though it is not visible.
5. Run the SharePoint configuration wizard but still same issue.

Before : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZJc4.png)

After : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY3e2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same symptoms as described, and none of the suggestions identified in question worked for me either.
We do now have a solution.
KB5002206 & KB5002207, released in May 2022, did solve our problem and the Edit Button returned across all of our browsers and environments.
In all cases it was necessary to use ctrl-F5 to force a refresh of the cache in the Browser.